# Why does MySql 8 choose a different index after running for a while?

Tags: mysql, indexing, mysql-8.0, cardinality

We're running a MySQL server (8.0.32) which has a table with a few million records. This table acts like a queue with a timestamp column of when the record is due for processing. Every day a few million records are added and deleted, the size roughly stays the same. The table looks like:

```
create table task (
  id bigint not null auto_increment,
  dueTs bigint not null,
  // other columns
)
```

This table also has an index on dueTs for fast lookup.

The application collects multiple records (about 100) at a time for parallel processing, any records in progress are excluded in the query like so:

```
SELECT * FROM task WHERE dueTs < UNIX_TIMESTAMP() AND id NOT IN (ids) LIMIT 100
```

This has worked fine for years until the database suddenly stopped using the correct index. It started using the primary key.

When we perform an `OPTIMIZE TABLE task;`, then the correct index is used again for a while. After about six hours the query becomes slow again because of the wrong key selection. We also tried to do `ANALYSE TABLE task;` but this didn't have the desired effect.

We can, of course, force the correct key in the query, but that doesn't explain why this keeps happening and why now.

What changed recently is that the database is purging old deleted data from another table which removed 500M+ records. I would not expect that cleaning another table could affect index selection on this table, but worth noting I think.

The java application which collects the records uses Hibernate. In this application we use a trick when there are no records to exclude. When the list is empty we add Long.MIN_VALUE to the list because Hibernate cannot handle an empty list. Does this affect cardinality?

Using the schema statistics, I've collected the cardinality of the primary key and the desired index using:

```
select INDEX_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, CARDINALITY 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS 
where TABLE_SCHEMA='myschema' and table_name='task';
```

This showed no changes in cardinality when the slow query started occurring. The number were:

```
"INDEX_NAME","COLUMN_NAME","CARDINALITY"
task_ix_dueTs,dueTs,131284
PRIMARY,id,47257372
```

Is there a way to know how and why MySQL chooses an index (other than explain)? Why would MySQL change its decision after a few hours?

Comment: Index statistic is approximate and iteratively dynamic (it is not recalculated, it is corrected). So the more time has passed since the last ANALYZE, the less accuracy. And the optimizer makes a mistake in its prediction. It decides that the amount of rows selected by dueTs < UNIX_TIMESTAMP() is too high, and this index usage is not reasonable.

Comment: Why doesn't ANALYSE table help while OPTIMIZE does change the behaviour? Why did it change after years of working as expected? Where can I find how it decided that  `dueTs < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` is not good enough?

Comment: *Why doesn't ANALYSE table help while OPTIMIZE does change the behaviour?* What percent of total rows matches `dueTs < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`? Approximately, of course..

Comment: never more than few thousand records so less than 0.1%. Unless there is downtime ofcourse but that was not case here.

Comment: If so then try to obtain extended execution plan (EXPLAIN ANALYZE FORMAT=TREE) for both cases.

Comment: As an experiment, try setting [information_schema_stats_expiry](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_information_schema_stats_expiry) to 0 and see if that fixes the issue. It's a new behavior in MySQL 8.0. The stats don't refresh for 24 hours by default, so if you are skewing the index by doing big batch deletions, it could confuse the optimizer. I agree it's unexpected that deletions in a different table would have an effect, but it's an easy experiment to try.

Comment: @Martin Please post your observations of trying Bill's setting of expiry to 0.  For you, it might be better to use expiry of 7200 (seconds) all day, every day to keep the optimizer on target.

Comment: I can't do that anymore. I've since made a workaround in the application so I can't reproduce this issue easily. I trying to reproduce this locally with a backup but no "luck" yet.

Comment: How big does this "queue" get?  If there are rarely more than a few dozen items in the queue and you can process 100 per second, then I question the need for a queue -- instead, simply "Don't queue it, just do it".

Comment: The tables contains items with timestamp upto two days in the future. They cannot be processed immediately because it has to wait for the timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
PRIMARY KEY(dueTs, id),  -- possibly faster lookup
INDEX(id)                -- to keep AUTO_INCREMENT happy
```

(And drop the current index on just `dueTs`.)

"A few million/day" = "a few dozen per second".  Is it sometimes bursty?  Does it sometimes get "behind"?  How long does it take to process each task?  How long for the "about 100"?  (I ask these questions because "100" may need tuning.)

Add `LIMIT 100` to your current `SELECT`; this should help performance when the processing gets backlogged.

Comment: `Limit 100` is in the actual query but I forgot it in the question. Added it just now. On peak loads there are ~100 threads processing records in parallel each taking <1s. The number of records can reach a few thousand under normal load but shouldn't reach 10k+, processing is fast enough to keep up most of the time. Changing the primary key may not work properly using hibernate, I'll look into this.

Comment: @Martin - 100 threads (processes) requires a lot of OS and MySQL overhead.  I recommend decreasing to, say, 30.

Comment: Threads was not the right word i guess, tasks managed by a adequate amount of threads in a thread pool. MySQL efficiency here is fine, hardly the heaviest thing it's doing, when it uses the right index that is.

Comment: @Martin - "Thread pools" are somewhat useful for starting up a new _connection_ to MySQL.  Once multiple threads are running, they compete with each other for resources.  I'm talking about the latter, not the former.

Comment: I can't really follow your comment. How are Thread pools 'useful for starting up a new connection'? Of course threads compete for resources but why is this a problem for the database selecting it's index? Why whould you assume this is an issue at all? What do you mean by 'The latter, not the former'?

Comment: @Martin - Grocery store analogy...  When 300 people are in the store at the same time, they are stumbling over each other and having trouble moving from one place to another. 30 people (3-5 in each of 8 aisles) might be more efficient because each person can mostly grab anitem and move on to the next place.  Having a pool of 300 carts outside encourages that many people to enter.

Comment: This analogy does not apply since the threads are mostly waiting for IO, they can do a lot of stuff parallel. Furthermore this is not relevant to the question as to why mysql would select a different index.

Comment: @Martin - I/O is probably single-threaded (unless you have RAID with striping).  As for not addressing the question -- Sorry, but I tend to digress from the _apparent_ question to what I perceive as the _real_ question -- how to speed up the task.